# uses of multithreading in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I know that a

Multithreaded processing can simultaneously run multiple procedures. For example, a word processor application can check spelling as a separate task while you continue to work on the document. Because multithreaded applications divide programs into independent tasks, they can substantially improve performance in the following ways:

• Multithreaded techniques can make your program more responsive because the user interface can remain active while other work continues.
• Tasks that are not currently busy can yield processor time to other tasks.
• Tasks that use a lot of processing time can periodically yield to other tasks.
• Tasks can be stopped at any time.
• You can set the priority of individual tasks higher or lower to optimize performance.

But i want to know

when i can use multithreading in vb.net ? any examples or an usual app use it

and what is the different if we use it in desktop apps or web applications

thanks .

Comment: Is this an homework question?

Comment: _When i can use multithreading in vb.net?_ Whenever you need to - question answered.

Comment: i'm a trainer "why do you think you might need to implement multithreading? " this is my Question

Comment: Rather than Taunt help the beginners!

Comment: This ain't taunt.  SO is here to help you solving a specific question.  You're asking for a solution about a problem that doesn't exist (or isn't mentioned) so that's why it was flagged as being to broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that multithreading is often used in image processing  and can often be done in parallel along with the rendering of an animation also, in GUI programming it often helps to have at least two threads when doing something slow, e.g. processing large number of files.
I thought it was the same in desktop apps and web applications though.

Comment: Just a side note - parallelism and asynchrony are different things!

Comment: FYI, I've used ALOT of multithreading when processing images. I've made an application to write text via Bitmap fonts, which includes recoloring in different ways.